# $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous $\implies f$ is bounded.

Tags: calculus, uniform-continuity, upper-lower-bounds

My first attempt:

Since uniform continuity implies continuity, $f((a,b))$ is an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$, which is bounded, thus $f$ is bounded.

Is this correct?

I was not convinced myself enough, so tried different approach (second attempt):

Fix $\epsilon>0$, then for all $x,y\in(a,b)$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$|x-y|\leq\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon.$$

And
\begin{align}
|f(c)| 
&= |f(c)-f(c+\delta)+f(c+\delta)| \\
&\leq |f(c)-f(c+\delta)|+|f(c+\delta)| \\
&<\epsilon+|f(c+\delta)| \\
&... \\
&<n\epsilon + |f(c+n\delta)|
\end{align}
where $c\in(a,b)$, $n$ satisfies $c+(n+1)\delta\geq b$.

I tried to bound $|f(c)|$ by a combination of $a,b,\epsilon$ and $\delta$, but it seemed not to work out.

Comment: $f$ being uniformly continuous in $(a,b)$ indicates it can be extended into a continuous function on $[a,b]$, and then applying extreme value theorem should do the job.

Comment: $f((a,b))$ doesn't have to be an open interval. It is surely not true if $f$ is a constant function for example. Moreover, the statement you try to prove is false for continuous functions in general, you need to use uniformly continuity here. Here is a hint for one possible solution: first show that a uniformly continuous function preserves Cauchy sequences.

Comment: the second approach, if done right (#), will give the desired result (which depends on $|b-a|$ being finite). (#) you should, e.g., determine the $n$ you are using).

Comment: The first attempt doesn't work as there exist continuous functions on open intervals which are not bounded. e.g. $\frac{1}{x}$. Your second approach might work, however it might help to notice that any continuous function on a closed bounded interval is bounded. That means you only need to worry about the endpoints of your open interval, this is where you need the uniform bounded condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first  try is incorrect, for example $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ on the interval $(0,1)$.

As for your second try, it's the right direction and can be made to work. First, we let $\varepsilon=1$. By uniform continuity, we have $\delta>0$ s.t $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<1$. Now we look at the closed interval $[a+\frac{\delta}{2},b-\frac{\delta}{2}]\subset (a,b)$ (we can assume $\delta$ is small enough s.t there is inclusion).

$f$ is continuous and hence bounded by some number $M$ on the closed interval we chose. Now let $x\in (a,b)$. If $x\in [a+\frac{\delta}{2},b-\frac{\delta}{2}]$ then $|f(x)|\leq M<1+M$. Otherwise if $x\in (a,b)\setminus[a+\frac{\delta}{2},b-\frac{\delta}{2}]$ there exists some $y\in [a+\frac{\delta}{2},b-\frac{\delta}{2}]$ s.t $|x-y|<\delta$. For this specific $y$ we have: $$|f(x)|\leq |f(x)-f(y)|+|f(y)|\leq 1+M$$ So $f$ is bounded by $1+M$.

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt is incorrect since a continuous functions need not be bounded on open intervals(consider $1/x$). To prove uniformly continuous functions are bounded I’d recommend showing that uniformly continuous functions preserve Cauchy sequences, so we can can extend the function to get a continuous function defined on $a$ and $b$, now use the fact that continuous functions are bounded on closed intervals.